# Log in with specific shell at terminal login

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal, gnu-screen, login

If I log in to a system over ssh, I can use the default shell with a simple `ssh user@host`, or specify something like `ssh user@host 'bash --norc --noprofile'` or `ssh user@host ksh`.

Is it possible to have similar behaviour when logging in on a local terminal, ie one where my terminal is connected directly to the system and I'm prompted for a username?

The specific usage scenario is running `screen` at login time, where a duff config option will prevent screen starting, and thus prevent the login succeeding. If I have ssh access, I can log in and run specific commands to fix things, but if I only have terminal access, I can't see how I could fix things up.

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the entry for `user` in `/etc/passwd` and change (a) the name from `user` to e.g. `user_mod_shell`, and (b) the default shell. The "who am i" chaos (probably without real problems) may be reduced by setting `USER` in the start processes.

Comment: I don't follow. So the result here would be two users, one for normal use, and one that solely exists for clearing up a login mess that the first had gotten itself into?

Comment: @me_and No you would have several names for the same user, one name for each shell. For each user name a different shell would be started.

Comment: exactly - also mentioned here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74961/changing-username-but-not-home-directory/74974#74974

Comment: Multiple entries with the same UID, then? Cunning!

Answer (score 1):

Put your terminal multiplexer (be it `tmux`, `screen` or something else) into your shell's initialization, but **do not *exec*** it (which one  would probably do) - that will jump back into shell if anything goes wrong in the terminal multiplexer.

To make it more user friendly, you can use the suggestion from comment by @EvanTeitelman and actually run `multiplexer && exit`, which will quit the session if the multiplexer exits normally.

Comment: Nice idea, but I'd prefer to avoid giving the user two shells to break out of in the normal use case.

Comment: You could do this: `screen && exit`. That way, if `screen` runs sucessfully, the shell will exit.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, we went with having the `.bash_profile` run `screen` if and only if the variable `$SSH_CONNECTION` was set. That means the normal use case (logging in via ssh) gets screen (and we can work around that by specifying `bash --noprofile` as the command to run on login), and for console connections we just get a regular session.

Of course, if we hose things somehow such that screen is executed on every login, we're still hosed. But there's no way of making this utterly foolproof.